# Nodejs Express router middleware for all methods except get

Tags: node.js, express

Is there a way to exclude a specific method (say GET) when creating a middleware for route methods that share part of the path?

For example, I have a lot of routes of the form `/api/item/*`. I want to have something like this to check for bad data

```
router.all('/api/item/*', (req, res, next) => {
  const { itemId } = req.body;
  if (!itemId) return res.sendStatus(404);

  /* rest of logic here */
  next()
});
```

But obviously I don't want GET to also go through this logic as it will have no `req.body`.

Any thoughts?

Comment: `if (req.method === 'GET') return next();`?

Comment: Doh! Totally overlooked that. Thank you @jonrsharpe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As posted in comments above one solution is `if (req.method === 'GET') return next();`

Another I thought of shortly after (though, not as elegant) is to order my route declarations as such:

```
router.get(...);
router.all(...);
```

Thus only applying the data-checking logic to non-GET requests.